# On the collector current formula used in LTSPICE

Tags: bjt, ltspice

Let us consider the following circuit drawn by LTSPICE:
[image]

1. Let us assume that we want to find the temperature for which the thermal voltage is
   VT=KT/q=25 mV
2. The Boltzmann constant is defined to be exactly K=1.380649×10−23 J⋅K−1
3. The default temperature in LTSPICE is 27 C which is T=273.15+27=300.15 K
4. elementary charge =1.60217662 × 10-19 coulombs
5. Therefore T=q*VT/K-273.15=16.963 C
6. On the transistor, we hit ctrl +right click and in the "SpiceLine" field we enter: temp=16.963
7. Let us assume the collector current is IC=1mA
8. So the Collector voltage is VC=10-6.8=3.2V
9. The Ebers-Moll formula:  IC=IS*(exp(VBE/VT)-1)-(IS/ALPHAR)*(exp(VBC/VT)-1)
10. Let us assume VBE is around 0.7 V, so VBC=0.7-3.2=-2.5 (AROUND).
11. exp(VBC/VT)=exp(-2500/25.865)=1.0543e-042
12. Therefor exp(VBC/VT) can be easily ignored and the EBERSMOLL formula is simplified as below:
    IC=IS*(exp(VBE/VT)-1+(1/ALPHAR))
13. The reverse current gain is BR=ALPHAR/(1-ALPHAR)=-1+(1/ALPHAR)
14. Therefore EBERS-MOLL formula is simplified as below:
    IC=IS*(exp(VBE/VT)+BR)
15. For VBE around 0.7 V, exp(VBE/VT)=1.4463e+012
16. The BR for 2N2222 is BR=3, which is negligible compared to exp(VBE/VT)=1.4463e+012, for our example EBERS-MOLL formula is simplified as below:
    IC=IS*exp(VBE/VT) or VBE=VT*Ln(IC/IS)
17. Let us assume that IS=1E-15 A, so VBE=25*Ln(1m/1E-15)=690.78mV
    18.We put IS=1E-15 A, VBE=690.78mV, when we run LTSPICE we expect to get IC=1mA but we get IC=.2 mA.

Question: which other parameter of the transistor should also be changed to get IC=1mA in LTSPICE?

Comment: Have you looked in the help under *LTspice > Circuit Elements > Q. ...* to see what are the default values for the rest of the parameters that you haven't used in the `.MODEL` card? Even if you are using the `2N2222`, it doesn't make use of every parameter.

Comment: Yes I did and try to change them too but no change to the results

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.idea2ic.com/PlayWithSpice/pdf/G%20U%20M%20M%20E%20L%20-%20P%20O%20O%20N.pdf) helps? Also, I see you're making a few assumptions in there, make sure those do not end up as wrong conditions for the next set of equations.

Comment: The assumptions are very reasonable such as 3 is ignored compared to 10 ^12

Comment: The assumption at point #17 is wrong.  `IS` is temperature dependent so it needs to be adjusted in your manual calculations.  If you're running at 16.963°C, you need to match what SPICE is doing under the hood.  Check out the equation involving `XTI` and `EG` here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/ref/npnbipolartransistor.html

Comment: Dear Ste Kulov you made a valuable point thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Ste Kulov](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/590724/on-the-collector-current-formula-used-in-ltspice#comment1548495_590777) mentions in the comments below, there is a temperature dependency (which I missed on your point #6). That changes `Is` to be (see [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/ref/npnbipolartransistor.html)):

$$I'_S=I_S\cdot\left(\dfrac{T_{\text{meas}}}{T_{\text{NOM}}}\right)^{XTI}\cdot\exp\left[-\dfrac{E_g}{kT_{\text{meas}}}\left(1-\dfrac{T_{\text{meas}}}{T_{\text{NOM}}}\right)\right] \tag{1}$$

Since the `.MODEL` does not provide any `XTI` or `Eg`, their values are set by the defaults to be `3.0` and `1.11`, respectively. With these, the new value is \$I_S=2.046\cdot 10^{-16}\$. Now, inserting this value in your step #17 results in \$V_{\text{BE}}=0.73044\;\text{V}\$. LTspice confirms it:

[image: test]

Comment: But you didn't do Point #6.  I think his problem is that he's not compensating for the temperature dependence of Is in Point #17.  He needs to manually calculate the new Is via XTI and Eg, as shown here:  https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/ref/npnbipolartransistor.html

Comment: @SteKulov You're right, I missed that. However, by accident, both of us haven't applied the temperature, which makes this result the one correct , as seen, Ic ~ 1 mA (as long as temperature is not considered). But *with* temperature, `XTI=3` by default (since it's not present in the `.MODEL` card), and `Is` is recalculated to be `1.65684e-16`, which results in `Vbe=0.7281`. Now, LTspice shows `0.926 mA`. Some of the other terms in `Is` would also be influenced by temperature, so I'd say it's closer to the truth.

Comment: But that's the whole point of the exercise.  Your example is already congruent across temperature, by default.  The questioner specifically wants to adjust for temperature and match SPICE's results to the calculations, such that it is congruent again.  BTW, your `Is` calculation is wrong.  I got `Is=2.0462e-16` which results in `Vbe=0.73044` and a collector current very close to `1mA`.

Comment: @SteKulov Darn it, I reversed the temperatures outside the log, and that `1e-16` abomination was an intermediary step, I actually got `2.509e-15`. I read the wrong line. I'll modify accordingly. In the impossible case you're thinking of upvoting, please don't.

Comment: LOL.  Too bad.  You can't tell me what to upvote.  Just a couple more edits, though.  It should be \$10^{-16}\$, not \$10^{-15}\$.  And adding parentheses for the `XTI` part of the equation will help the readability.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Did u use Kelvin or C for the temperature in the Equation (1)?

Comment: @Aria It's Kelvin, and don't forget that \$E_g\$ is \$1.11\cdot q\$, with \$q=1.602\cdot 10^{-19}\$, therefore \$v_T\$ also changes.

Comment: @SteKulov Thanks, but the point was that I was sloppy (I haven't even seen the temperature part until you pointed it out, & co), and carelessness should not be rewarded.

Comment: Thank you both @SteKulov and @ a concerned citizen.